# Need a login page using Entity Framework, SQL Server in MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I need to design a login page using Entity Framework,SQL Server in MVC. I've tried several ways but they did not work correctly, even the result is true, program don't direct me the main page. Need help right now.

Here is my:

Controller

```
MainEntities1 db = new MainEntities1();
public ActionResult Index(Admin a)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Admin admin = db.Admin.Find(1);
            db.Admin.Add(a);
            if (a.Password.Equals(admin.Password))
                    return RedirectToAction("Main");
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

View

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Admin</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the table 'Admin' I have id which is primary key and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this as,

View :-

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Admin</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new {  @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { id="Password" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" id="BtnLogin" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
```

$("#BtnLogin").click(function(){
var data=new {"Password":$("#password").val()}
`$.ajax({ url: "../ControllerName/Login",type: "Post",data: data,dataType: "json",async: false,contentType: false,processData: false,success: function (ReturnValue) {if (ReturnValue == "Error") {alert('Error');}else{window.location.href = ReturnValue;}},error: function (err) {alert('Error');
},});});`

Controller Code :-

```
public JsonResult Login(Admin a)
{ string Output="";if (ModelState.IsValid){            
Admin admin = db.Admin.Find(1);if 
(a.Password.Equals(admin.Password)){
Output="../home";}else{OutPut="Error";}}
    return this.json(Output);
}
```